# Best way to cache data while switching between list view and detail view in Angular 12

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have a simple Angular App with two components, a list view and details view. Users can switch between them. Both components use multiple async pipes.

I want to minimise the amount of http requests to the backend. I like the idea of caching data with RxJs `Observables` and the `shareReplay()` function to avoid the multiple async pipes cause multiple http requests. So I wrote the following service:

```js
const URL = 'http://localhost:8080/items';
const CACHE_SIZE = 1;

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ItemsService {

  private _cache$: Observable<Item[]>;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
  }

  findAll(): Observable<Item[]> {
    if (!this._cache$) {
      this._cache$ = this._requestItems().pipe(
        shareReplay(CACHE_SIZE)
      );
    }
    return this._cache$;
  }

  private _requestItems() {
    return this.http.get<Item[]>(URL).pipe(
      map(items => items.map(item => this._transformItem(item)))
    );
  }

  ...
}
```

Next I need a second function `findSingle(id): Observable<Item>` for details view and I also want to reuse the cached data when users switch between the two components. The backend provides a second resource `http://localhost:8080/items/{id}` because I don't want to load the hole list of items for showing only one of them on the details view. What is the best strategy to reuse the already cached data? I have two problems the my current approach:

1. The new findSingle-function would need an other observable-type (`Observable<Item>` instead of `Observable<Item[]>`).
2. The user could use a deep-link directly to an item and then switch to the list view, so I have no idea when data has to get loaded from backend.

Comment: I don't actually really understand your issues, seem you are already using shareReplay for all items. as for your questions... 1. Write such a function as you seem to have the API to get a item? 2. You already have the shareReplay on the items, so if they exist, that will be returned. Don't really understand the comment on second question I have no idea when data has to get loaded from backend. Well, assumingly when you are on the list page the values should be fetched in OnInit, right?

Comment: The ```findSingle(id: string)``` could look like:
```findSingle(id: string): Observable<Item> {
    if (!this._cache$) {
      this._cache$ = this._requestSingleItem().pipe(
        shareReplay(CACHE_SIZE)
      );
    }
    return this._cache$;
}
```

1. This code breaks because `cache` is an `Observable<Items[]>`, `requestSingleItem()` returns `Observable<Item>`.
2. Assuming that the user first calls the details view. On switching to list view `cache` would contain a single item and the user would see only one element on the list view.

Hope this makes it clearer.

Comment: OK, got a bit clearer to me now, but .... so do you want to use an api endpoint for getting one item like saying in question, or do you want to use the cached data? Your comments are kinda contradicting :)

Comment: That's right :)  Maybe the problem is that I try to mix aspects. If `ListItem` and `DetailsItem` where different entities, there would be no problem. Two entities, two REST-Resources => Two Angular-Services with two caches.

I guess my goal was to cache all Items a user has ever requested in a global cache, no matter on which view. On the other side I wanted to decide in the service if its necessary to load the hole list if items or if a single item was requested the first time. Think I would need a cache where I can incremental add elements for this.

Comment: Don't try to achieve both getting all items and a single item to a single function. You can have 2 functions, one for getting a single item, one for getting all items. They can use the same data, for the single item you just filter out the one you want for all items. But of course that means that you need to fetch all items initially. Anyways, I would have two different functions, you can cache both if you want, but don't try to make them all work for one function.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @AT82. Here is my new approach. `findSingle` and `findAll` are two separated functions:

```js
const URL = environment.apiUrl + '/items';
const CACHE_SIZE = 1;

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ItemService {

  private _collectionCache$: Observable<Item[]>;
  private _singleCache: Map<string, Observable<Item>>;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    this._singleCache = new Map<string, Observable<Item>>();
  }

  findAll(): Observable<Item[]> {
    if (!this._collectionCache$) {
      this._collectionCache$ = this._requestAllItems().pipe(
        shareReplay(CACHE_SIZE)
      );
    }
    return this._collectionCache$;
  }

  findSingle(id: string): Observable<Item> {
    if (!this._singleCache.has(id)) {
      this._singleCache.set(id,
        this._requestSingleItem(id).pipe(
          shareReplay(CACHE_SIZE)
        )
      );
    }

    let result = this._singleCache.get(id);
    if (result) {
      return result;
    } else {
      throw Error('Unexpected cache result');
    }
  }

  private _requestAllChallenges() {
    return this.http.get<Item[]>(URL).pipe(
      map(challenges => challenges.map(item => this._mapItem(item)))
    );
  }

  private _requestSingleItem(id: string) {
    return this.http.get<Item>(URL + '/' + id).pipe(
      map(item => this._mapItem(item))
    );
  }

  ...
}
```

If the user switches from list view to details view a second request is necessary to get the single item into the `singleCache`. But its better separated. Another approach could be to differ between `ListItem` and `DetailItem`, so that there are two Api-resources and two different Angular services.